# Basic Java work

Tags: java

I am learning Java. I am fairly new to this and just doing some practice exercises,

This is what it says I must do, I have attempted it (please see my coding below) I need some help with some error messages that I keep getting.

Create a class `Student` to describe a student with the following attributes:

- student ID
- name
- level

with appropriate data types.

This information should be provided, when an object is created. The program should be able to provide each piece of information, when requested. Please also write a method to input a fixed number (for instance 5) of grades (using the Scanner class) and to calculate and print their average.

A main method to run the program should be devised so that the required information is inputted via the keyboard.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class student{

    public static void main (String args []){

        Scanner grade = new Scanner(System.in);
        int studentgrade;
        int studentid;
        String studentname;

        System.out.println("enter student grade") ;
        int studentgrade = grade.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter your studentID here");
        int studentid = grade.nextInt();

        System.out.println("type your student name here");
        String studentname = grade.next();

        answer = studentgrade + studentid + studentname;                        
    }
}
```

I have updated the coding after your feedback and now it says,

> variable student grade is already defined in method main

I'm so confused i hate this :(

Comment: Just because you are new doesn't mean you shouldn't put any effort into reading documentation or tutorials. (I'm not saying you haven't put any effort, I'm saying you haven't shown any.) Also, read the FAQ. Follow the guidelines.

Comment: Please use capital letters where appropriate. I don't even think your print statements will work since `System` is not capitalized.

Comment: Yes sorry just noticed and changed them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//import java.util.scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class student
{
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        Scanner grade = new Scanner(System.in);
        int studentgrade=0;
        int studentid=0;
        String studentname="";

        System.out.println("enter student grade");
        studentgrade = grade.nextInt(); // the error is here apparently ? it highlights this line yellow and says ";" expected

        System.out.println("enter your studentID here");
        studentid = grade.nextInt();

        System.out.println("type your student name here");
        studentname = grade.next();

        int answer = studentgrade + studentid;

        System.out.println("answer = " + answer + "student name = " + studentname);
        //+ student name    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is:

`";"expected`

Means that you are missing a semicolon in your code.

`answer = studentgrade + studentid + student name`

should be

`answer = studentgrade + studentid + studentname;`

Answer (score 0):

problem with this line

```
int studentgrade.next.int();
```

it is neither and assignment nor a statement. what are you trying to do with this?

it should be something like this:

```
int studentgrade = grade.nextInt();
```

And then

```
int studentid = next.int;
```

should be

```
int studentid = grade.nextInt();
```

And same problem is with

```
string studentname = next.string;
```

it should be

```
String studentname = grade.next();
```

Lots of other changes it requires in terms of being a compilable unit such as scanner should be Scanner, string should be String and system should be System. Please read java naming conventions and use standard class names as is at least.

Comment: Also there is a colon instead of a semi-colon at system.out.println("enter your studentID here"):

Comment: Thanks now it says "identifier expected' ? can you help?

Comment: Next level of help would be to write this code myself and that i don't want to do. sorry :). you have to try it yourself use google :)